# Timex Device Agent 3.0 does not detect Timex Run Trainer (USB)

Tags: usb, wine, detect, gps

I installed Device Agent and it is running with Wine. It lets me login to my account on TrainingPeaks (on the web) but I cannot upload anything since my Timer Run Trainer GPS is not detected by Timex Device Agent.
Totally new to Ubuntu and Wine, I really have no idea what to try. 
Any help or suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest wine 1.7.x – it solved my connection issue with Garmin Mapsource (6137) connecting to eTrex Legend with a USB-Serial adapter. See: [How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/installing-and-configuring-wine)

Also important to ensure the com port under wine is linked to /dev/ttyUSB0, and permissions are OK.

Do:

> ls -l /dev/tty*

You should see a device called "ttyUSB0".  You should see it belong to the dialout group. Add yourself to the group:

> sudo adduser yourusername dialout

Reboot computer.

Make the device visible as "com1" port under wine:

> cd ~/.wine/dosdevices
>
> ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 "com1"

Comment: thanks for the reply and I know it was a while back. anyhow, I have been using windows to access my gps until now. I am trying again with linux, tried your suggestion but do not see ttyUSB0. any ideas what to do next?